# In iOS mobile app, typing on textfield is very slow ,taking around 10-12 seconds to enter one alphabet

Tags: ios, iphone, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

I am automating iOS mobile app using appium automation tool. I am using:

- iPhone iOS : 13.3
- Appium version: 1.15.0
- xcode: 11.3.1

Issue is, I am able to launch the app, but then it is taking too much time to enter keywords in username and password field. Due to this issue, login script takes longer time and it times out which causes failure.

Comment: As I remember, It is because Appium itself. However, It is just a guess.

Comment: Please share the code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of improving typing speed two of the appium iOS capabilities can help

1. If you are on simulator use "sendKeyStrategy" as "oneByOne".
2. Secondly, add "maxTypingFrequency", the default value you can set 60

These two will surely improve typing speed on text fields.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround:** Appium provides set clipboard functionality to set the content of the system clipboard.
The iOS clipboard can be loaded with the desired string and then pasted into a text field element.

**Steps:**

1. Set clipboard text -

   ```
   driver.set_clipboard(input_text)
   ```
2. Long press on input text field -

   ```
   from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction
   actions = TouchAction(driver)
   actions.long_press(text_field_el, duration=5000).perform()
   ```
3. Select "Paste" option to paste clipboard text content -

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_class_name("XCUIElementTypeMenuItem").click() # Paste option element
   ```

**Appium issues:**

1. [iOS 13 - Appium: SendKeys issue with slowness #13455](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/13455)
2. [sendKeys on XCUIElementTypeTextView is typing 1 character at a time and fails out with NoSuchDriverError exception #13444](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/13444)